# Run command for multiple directories?

Tags: exiftool

I have a list of directories in a text file for which I want to run an exiftool command. Is there a built-in way in exiftool to do so or do I have to use shell scripting for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`-@`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#ARGFILE) option is what you want to use.  As long as each directory in the text file is on a separate line, just add `-@ /path/to/textfile.txt` to your base command.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to save script in text file as .bat file so it runs every line of script with given directory. It's fairly easy to attach script to list of locations.
Example where two lines run from different folder and output .csv with four columns:

```
    exiftool -p "FolderA $filename $DateTimeOriginal" -q -f -r -csv dir E:\...\FolderA > E:/.../FolderA.csv
    exiftool -p "FolderB $filename $DateTimeOriginal" -q -f -r -csv dir E:\...\FolderB > E:/.../FolderB.csv
```